# Loop without selecting cells

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop

I'd like to loop without selecting cells. Range B:B will contain a list of values which I'd like numbered: `10`, `20`, `30` etc. I have an idea of how this could be accomplished but it doesn't work yet:

```
Dim i as integer
i = 1
Do While i < 200
    If Range("Bi") <> "" Then
        Range("Ai")= i*10
    end if
    i = i + 1
Loop
End sub
```

Does anyone know a way to accomplish something like this?

And would this work or wouldn't it make any sense at all?:

```
Dim i as integer
Dim a as String
Dim b as String
Dim c as integer
i = 1

Do While i < 200
    a = "A"& i
    b = "B"& i
    c = i * 10
    If Range(b) <>"" Then
        Range(a) = c
    End if
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Cells to use numeric indexes to rows and columns, if you don't want to create strings of range addresses.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Long

i = 1
c = 10

Do While i < 200
    Cells(i, 2).Value = c
    i = i + 1
    c = c + 10
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks for this cleaver sollution! It does the same as my own code but is much slimmer&cleaner.( in my case, i only need to add the if function, because I'd like it to stop counting when at the end of the list, or better (Do While <> "")

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there with your first snippet. This works:

```
Sub SetNumbers()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Do While i < 200
        If Range("B" & i) <> "" Then
            Range("A" & i) = i * 10
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

The key is to make the Range selection like this: `Range("A" & i)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Anwser**

I've tryed it an this seems to work

```
Dim i as integer
Dim a as String
Dim b as String
Dim c as integer
i = 1

Do While i < 200
    a = "A"& i
    b = "B"& i
    c = i * 10
    If Range(b) <>"" Then
        Range(a) = c
    End if
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: More often than not you can discard the extra string vars and just use simple string concatenation within the [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) definition; e.g. `Range("B" & i)`